# When pinned to a git branch, how exactly does npm's cache work?

Tags: npm

We're running into a really interesting edge-case that I thought I would post about, see if anyone can shed some light towards.

We have a project that is pinned to an npm module via git repo url:

```
dependencies: {
  "whatever": "git+ssh://whatever@whatever.com/whatever#bugfix/foo"
}
```

We have two branches out on origin:

```
bugfix/foo
bugfix/updated-foo
```

The second branch, `bugfix/updated-foo` was rebased off of `bugfix/foo` on the second to last commit of `bugfix/foo`.

In both branches, the `version` in `package.json` is set to `5.0.2` as they were both branched from `master`. Our latest release is `5.0.2`.

Finally, my question: **Does npm cache modules based upon the `version` specified in `package.json`?** The behavior we're seeing is that sometimes one branch will be checked out upon building the project, other times the other.

This has got us all kind of confused as we made the assumption that the branch name was used as the unique identifier in this scenario.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After blowing away my cache and then bumping the version in one of the branches, I was able to see that node modules are indeed cached by the `version` key in `package.json` and not by the branch name as we had previously thought.

Makes sense why we were seeing some wonkiness!

Thanks :)